# Having trouble mapping Laravel public folder with a vhost on MAMP

Tags: laravel, apache, mamp, vhosts

I've got a Laravel project called "test" running on MAMP on my mac. I've uncommented the vhosts include line in httpd.conf and included this below in the vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public"
    ServerName testapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to "testapp.dev" in my browser it just says the old

```
testapp.dev’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I'm not sure if I've missed something or what. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

(This is a repost but more clear)

Comment: i don't know about mac, but did you also added `127.0.0.1    testapp.dev` in the hosts ?

Comment: If you're using a mac, why not install valet?

Comment: @Polaris I installed it with composer but it says valet is not a command in my terminal.

Comment: You need to follow the [instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet#installation) **Make sure the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory is in your system's "PATH".**. Use *.test* instead of *.dev* and ditch MAMP and install Valet. *.dev is owned by Google.*

Comment: I got valet installed and I'm using .test. I tried linking an parking but test.test just returns "It works!". I did that in the laravel project in htdocs. Do I not need MAMP if I'm using valet?

Comment: @Kyslik Every .test url I go to just ends up at `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en~orig`, which is just `localhost` and not a laravel app. Linking or parking with valet does nothing. I don't even know how I made this web server folder.

Answer (score 1):

So I ditched MAMP and used valet. I had some problems with that just going to localhost which was some random background apache server which I stopped and then everything worked! :)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using windows edit `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and if you are using unix edit `/etc/hosts` file and add this row at the end of file:

`127.0.0.1    testapp.dev`

Comment: I'm on a Mac, as specified in the first sentence. I don't have an etc folder in my MAMP directory, but I do have one in /Library/etc from the MAMP directory. That etc folder, however, doesn't have a host file, all it has is a folder called "ImageMagick-6". Anywhere else it could be? Yes, I have enabled the viewing of hidden files.

Comment: @Techmo Go to the terminal and type nano /etc/hosts - you most definitely have it. I would reccommend reading up on installing Valet (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet). It makes hosting laravel and other stuff local on a mac, a breeze.

Comment: @Techmo open finder then press `cmd+shif+G` and then write `/etc/hosts`. now open hosts file with sublime and add that line at the end of file

Comment: @MariusEngenHaugen I nano'd the file and added the line but now it says that testapp.dev refused to connect. At the top of the file there's the same line but with localhost instead of testapp.dev. Also, I installed valet with composer but when I go to run its commands in terminal, it says that valet doesn't exist.

Comment: @Techmo have you added "~/.composer/vendor/bin" to your $PATH?

Comment: @MariusEngenHaugen Yes. I've got it working now but when I link an app, all I get is "It works!". That's all I get for anything on that matter.

Comment: You might need to stop apache, if you have it running @Techmo